# EWS Throttling every 30 min

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Every 30 minutes I synchronize all calendars in my department, using EWS.

Though, after migrating to Outlook 365 Cloud Solutions, we are having problems with throttling of requests to the EWS. The synchronizer runs until it's blocked -> shuts down -> and starts up again 30 minutes later.

How do I resolve the circumstances that result in the blocking of requests, and without using PowerShell since I don't have the relevant Adminstrator access to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be to review your code to see why you are being throttled, some simple changes to your code may fix the throttling issue eg if you using Load instead of Loadpropertiesforitems https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/03/16/loading-properties-for-multiple-items-with-one-call-to-exchange-web-services/ this can results in a lot more unnecessary requests that will results in you being throttled. Also make sure you are using the X-AnochorMailbox header https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2990048/ews-throttling-occurs-after-a-migration-of-office-365-dedicated-itar-t

Because Office365 is a Shared service you can't change the throttle policy settings (even if you did have the rights) so you should first make your code robust enough to deal with throttling when it happens. Another solution maybe to use EWS Impersonation so you can change the request against the Target Mailboxes throttling policy.